# Regular expression to extract everything between braces in unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed, grep

I am trying to extract everything between braces from a text file and write the output to another text file. I was able to construct a regular expression to match everything between {} and it works fine (I wrote a simple java program to test it) but I not very strong in unix hence not sure how to use this regular expression in unix.

The below regular expression matches everything between {} (works in jedit too)

```
\{([^}]+)\}
```

I tried the below sed command,

```
cat samplefile | sed -e 's/.*\{\([^}]+\)\}.*/\1/g'
```

I am getting the below error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Between I found a regex to match everything between [] and it works great. Not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone help me fix my regex issu?

```
cat file |sed -e 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g'
```

**Edit 1:**

**Solution:**

```
cat file | sed -e 's/.*{\([^}]\+\)}.*/\1/g'  --> works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the + quantifier

Answer (score 1):

I know that you already solved the question, but most [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) machines have a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) interpreter and that language has a built-in module that does the hard job of parsing text whit this kind of delimiters, it's `Text::Balanced`. Here a test:

Assuming this random text (taken from the question :-), added some text between curly braces and saved as `infile` file:

```
I am trying to extract {everything between braces} from a text file and 
write the output to another text file. I was able to {construct a regular 
expression} to match everything between {} and it works fine (I wrote a 
simple {java program} to test it) but I not {very strong} in unix hence not 
sure how to use this regular expression in unix.
```

The program `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Balanced qw<extract_bracketed>;

my $str = do { undef $/; <> };

while ( my @result = extract_bracketed( $str, '{}', '[^{]*' ) ) { 
    last unless defined $result[0];
    $result[0] =~ s/\n//g;
    $result[0] = substr $result[0], 1, length( $result[0] ) - 2;
    printf qq|%s\n|, $result[0];
}
```

reads the whole file in a variable and parses it looking for a pair of curly braces, for each loop saves in first position of the array `@result` the text inside them, so then I remove any newline character, leading and trailing curly braces and print it.

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
everything between braces
construct a regular expression

java program
very strong
```

Note that it parses correctly a blank pair in the third line. Also other with a newline inside them (second line) and when there are several in the same line, like in the fourth one.